# Expanding columns in lookup fields

Tags: rest, odata

Using the SharePoint 2013 REST API,

Can I get more than one column from the lookup column by using the `$select` and `$expand` endpoints?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can expand multiple columns:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=Title,LookupField1/FieldToBeExpanded1,LookupField2/FieldToBeExpanded2&$expand=LookupField1,LookupField2
```

Comment: Too simplistic. Doesn't define `FieldToBeExpanded1` and `FieldToBeExpanded2`, and seems to be talking about having multiple lookups, not multiple fields from a single lookup's backend list.

Answer (score 6):

Below query finally worked for me:

- **Cats** is a list of cats, with a **Title** field and **Merged** as a calculated field
- In the **MainFlat** list, **Cat** is a lookup field to the **Merged** field on the **Cats** list

  ```
  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainFlat')/items?$select=Title,number,Cat/Merged&$expand=Cat&$filter=Cat/Merged eq '"+Merged+"'"
  ```

If you bring in multiple fields using the settings of that `Cat` lookup column in the **MainFlat** list, you can bring them in on the REST call. For example, if you want the cat's name from the `Title` field, too, and you specify that you also want to show the `Title` field in the `Cat` field's settings, you can then add `Cat/Title`:

```
$select=Title,number,Cat/Merged,Cat/Title&$expand=Cat
```

It will not work until you add the `Title` field in the settings for the `Cat` lookup field, though.

Comment: i have problems @imanabidi that solved by your answers thanks ;)

Comment: i have this problem after 3 years and your answer helped me again. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consider your lookup column name as "**Field1LUP**" of "**List1**"
and "**Title**" field of "**List2**" is source to lookup field.

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=Field1LUP/Title&$expand=Field1LUP
```

Answer (score 0):

The REST API and OData request parameters can be used to request additional information from a lookup field's list. As an example, let's say we have an `Employees` list with a `Department` lookup field that has `Name` and `Branch` fields on that `Department` list. If we need to get the Employee's `Name` and `Id`, but also get the department's name and branch, we can use this GET request:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employees')/items?$select=Name,Id,Department/Name,Department/Branch&$expand=Department
```

This gets the employee's name, ID, and then we expand the Department lookup field and read the department name (`Department/Name`) and branch (`Department/Branch`). The requirement is to expand the lookup list and prefix every field you want off of its list with the list name. One important note is that this will not work until you select in the settings of the `Department` lookup field, in the `Employees` list, that you want the additional `Branch` column to appear on the `Employees` list.

More information can be found at:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this got downvoted originally because it didn't answer how you would get **multiple** columns. Provided an edit.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a lookuplist/value can lookup list be equal to a guid? My lookup lists contain / and it's causing problems within the query

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125304)