# Filter SharePoint list using Rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

There is a SharePoint list with a lookup column. Now I want to search the SharePoint list with filter on lookup column. 
E.g. :

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/items?$expand=lookupcolumn&$select=Title,parentlookupcol/lookupcolumn&$filter=substringof('US2017 - 0002',lookupcolumn)
```

Syntax `filter = lookupcolumn eq 'value'` is working, but I want to filter the list even if I pass part of the string.

Please share an example of how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance
usha

Answer (score 0):

isn't the problem that you are filtering by the lookupcolumn value and not the lookup column Title?

you'll have to expand the lookupcolumn and apply the filter to the text field

[Expanding columns in lookup fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103298/expanding-columns-in-lookup-fields)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.  Query worked with this https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/items?$expand=lookupcolumn&$select=Title,parentlookupcol/lookupcolumn&$filter = lookupcolumn eq 'value'. But when using "https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/items?$expand=lookupcolumn&$select=Title,parentlookupcol/lookupcolumn&$filter=substringof('US2017 - 0002',lookupcolumn) 
" , it failes

Comment: I had expanded the lookup column, but still no luck

Comment: have you tried $filter=substringof('US2017 - 0002',lookupcolumn\Title)

Comment: Yes I tried... But it give me http 500 error